# Filtering time and date data from MySQL using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm not a PHP/MySQL programmer, but I'm trying to help my friend that just opened his own barbershop by creating a very simple website for him. I added to the site a contact form that sends the info to a MySQL database. That part works perfectly. Now I'm tryin to display upcoming appointments by showing only the ones scheduled for the day.

```
<?php

 $sql = 'SELECT * FROM tbl_content';

 $query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

 if (!$query) {die ('SQL Error: ' . mysqli_error($conn));
 }

date_default_timezone_set("America/New_York");
$dateToday = date('m/d/Y');
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
   {
     $whatService = $row['service'];
     $nameData = $row['name'];
     $justName = explode(" ", $nameData);
     $timeData = $row['Time'];
     $modifiedTime = date("g:i A", strtotime($timeData));
     $currentTime = $theDate = $row['date'];
     $modDate = date('m/d/Y', strtotime($theDate ));

 if ($modDate  === $dateToday) {
    echo '<li  class="w3-bar">
       <div class="w3-bar-item">'.$justName[0].'</div>
       <span class="w3-bar-item  w3-right">'.$modifiedTime.'</span>
       <span class="w3-bar-item  w3-center w3-right">'.$whatService.'</span> 
  </li>';
   }
  }
?>
```

This part works just fine, and it shows exactly what I need. But this is the issue. I would like to only show upcoming appointments for the rest of the day. What I mean is that, for example, if it is 3:00 PM right now, just show appointments that are scheduled for after 3:00 PM. I tried to do this by adding this to the condition:

```
if ($modDate  === $dateToday && date("g:i A",$modifiedTime) >= date("g:i A",strtotime("now"))) {...
```

I also tried

```
if ($modDate  === $dateToday && $modifiedTime >= date("g:i A",strtotime("now"))) {..
```

I'm not sure what I need to do. Please notice that I only included part of the code. If more is needed I will. I would appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: you should add the date\time check to the query. not select everything and filter afterwards, could be as easy as adding `WHERE your_date_field >NOW()`

Comment: @tim is right. If you need help with that, add your MySQL query to the question

Comment: Thanks. I just added the query.

Comment: no, you didn't, whats `$sql` ??

Comment: Sorry. The kids are back from school, I can't concentrate now. I added it and used your suggestion and changed it to `$sql = 'SELECT * FROM `tbl_content` WHERE `Time` >= NOW()';` and it seems to be working as desired.

Comment: @tim, could you add your suggestion as a response. It worked perfectly. I actually was able to also eliminate the date filter from the PHP `if` statement, and filter everything in the initial query `$sql = 'SELECT * FROM `tbl_content` WHERE `Time` > NOW() AND `date` = CURDATE()';`. Thanks for the suggestion. I learned something new today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easier and more efficient to handle this filtering at the database level, its what they are designed for. Yours is quite a simple one, assuming your DB servers date is in the same time zone as your barbershop, or the offset for insertion and extraction are the same add a where clause to the query to only return appointments for today and due after the current time:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_content WHERE Time > CURTIME() AND date = CURDATE()
```

I would also suggest storing date-time together (datetime field type), this makes lot of queries easier to manage, and a fraction faster.

If you had one field the query would be:

SELECT * FROM tbl_content WHERE DateTme > NOW() AND date(DateTime) = CURDATE()

You should also add indexes to `Time` and `date`